# PHP XMLRPC Moodle function calling parameters do not match signature

Tags: php, moodle, xml-rpc

I cannot figure out how to properly pass the required arguments for the function core_user_get_users_by_field

The Moodle function documentation is included below.

Here is the function in the Moodle class that is not working properly.

```
// The getUser function obtains information for a Moodle user identified by its id.
function getUser($user_id) {
// Clear last error.
$this->error = null;

// Create XML for the request. XML must be set properly for this to work.
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request('core_user_get_users_by_field', array(array((string) $user_id)), array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));
```

This snippet is the part that is throwing the error.

```
array(array((string) $user_id))
```

> FUNCTION
>   DOCUMENTATION---------------------------------------------------
>   core_user_get_users_by_field
>
> Retrieve users information for a specified unique field - If you want
>   to do a user search, use core_user_get_users()
>
> Arguments field (Required)
>           the search field can be 'id' or 'idnumber' or 'username' or 'email'
>
> General structure
>
> string   //the search field can be
>                       'id' or 'idnumber' or 'username' or 'email'
>
> XML-RPC (PHP structure)
>
> [field] => string REST (POST parameters)
>
> field= string
>
> values (Required)
>
> General structure
>
> list of (  string   //the value to match ) XML-RPC (PHP structure)
>
> [values] =>
>       Array 
>           (
>           [0] => string
>           ) REST (POST parameters)
>
> values[0]= string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out....See snippet below.

```
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request('core_user_get_users_by_field', array("id", array((string)$user_id)), array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));
```